# open google search page

Tags: android

I have a text box , and user enters text on here , I want to know how can I handle this textbox so when users enters a text , It opens google search page and search that text , I do not want to using apis , just opens google website in browser and searches for text .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
String term = "TechnoTalkative";   // term which you want to search for
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
String term =tb.getText.toString();<-- get from your textbox(tb)
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the navigator directly, you can do that:

```
String search = "what is android or something";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/#hl=eng&output=search&q="+ search));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```